# Magento 2 : How to Add New Colum on Checkout Cart Page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, shopping-cart

I want to add  new custom column after product name column on cart page. See below screen-sort.

[image]

Any one have idea?

Now i also want to rename item column name  to my-item.
[image]

see my attachment.

Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: Can you specify what actual you want to do?

Comment: I want to add 1 extra column i am new in magento2 so i dont know please check my screen shot.

Comment: You can do this by overiding that into your custom extension.